# why is my onPrepareOptionsMenu not getting called?

Tags: java, android

```
public class BFragmentTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recents, container, false);
     }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        MenuItem filter = menu.findItem(R.id.filter);
        MenuItem refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
        //depending on you conditions, either enable/disable
        filter.setEnabled(false);
        refresh.setEnabled(false);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call my `onPrepareOptionsMenu` inside my Fragment class, buts its not getting called. I want to refresh my menu item when i click on an `action tab` inside my `action bar`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656953/onprepareoptionsmenu-not-getting-called-in-fragments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onAttach` method

Comment: Is there an advantage to calling in onAttach rather than onCreateView ?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev: I get a null pointer exception in my onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

Comment: @theJava at leas it's called, right? :) You probably should call `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu` before everything else

Comment: For who arrives here using API 22.1.1 I just found out that the libray is bugged and onPrepareOptionsMenu is skipped from calling... Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/30199286/3397345

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and in my case there was an error in my xml layout file for one of the sub-activity.

Surprisingly Eclipse didn't show the error but after removing it, the program worked.