# onPrepareOptionsMenu in Fragment not being called as of AppCompat v22 (API 10)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

We have an app that uses `AppCompatActivity` with multiple fragments, each of which contribute to the options menu. (i.e. the fragments override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and insert their own menu items)

The fragments also override `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, in order to conditionally enable/disable certain menu items based on the state of the app.

Prior to the updated version (22) of appcompat, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` function was called for each fragment, and everything was working correctly. But now, it's no longer being called.

This behavior is only present in API 10.  In newer APIs it works correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: I lost all the morning logging my app, until I found this question and answer. Thanks for pointing it out.
I confirm that with 5.1.1 devices, onPrepareOptionsMenu is called while on minor version it is not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little digging, I found this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170630

Let's hope this is resolved in the next release of appcompat!